# Creating .finished file with the folder names under a directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I've seen example of it as batch command but it is not working for me.

I searched and there is a command like this :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

but it puts `./` to every folder name, is there a command that will give just folder names or how can i delete the first `./` characters in my script ?

After that i will read them line by line and create the `.finished` files with touch commands.

Any help would be approciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a reason that the `./` prefix is problematic (other than your own aesthetic sense)? `touch foo/bar/.finished` should work just as well as `touch ./foo/bar/.finished`...

Comment: if you put `.` as a directory to search in **find(1)**  it will prepend `./` to every path it generates.  A solution to this is to do `find *` instead of `find .`  but that has some drawbacks (`*` is expanded by the shell, not by find and uses a different approach, and doesn't include dot/hidden entries, like `.profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using `cut` command we can discard `./` from the list of folder name.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d|cut -c 3-
```

Or you can use this option too, suggested by @Luis

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d|sed -e 's:^\./::'
```

Comment: `sed -e 's:^\./::'` will do it better (it won't do in case the path doesn't begin with `./`.

Comment: Ok i will add the option too

Comment: It would be something like `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | sed -e 's:^\./::'`.  You can even do `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | sed 's:^\./\(.*\):\1/.finished:'` and get directly the names of the files you wan to touch.  Or even `touch $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | sed 's:^\./\(.*\):\1/.finished:')` to create the files in one command.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%P\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed` to eliminate the first two characters, like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | sed 's?^[.]/??'
```